# How to use the "All" data category?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

The ServiceSDK docs suggest that we can provide the virtual data category “All”, which is visible in the portal, as the `rootDataCategory` for the `SCSServiceConfiguration` in the ServiceSDK.   But when I provide “All” (as in the example code), I get an error that says “invalid data category group or data category”.

Here is the sample code from the docs:

```
// Create configuration object with init params
02  {{SCSServiceConfiguration *config = [[SCSServiceConfiguration alloc] }}
03     {{initWithCommunity:NSURL URLWithString:@}}{{"[https://mycommunity.example.com }}
04     dataCategoryGroup:@"Regions"
05      rootDataCategory:@"All"];
```

Is there a mechanism to make "All" work and get all of my root-level data categories into the Knowledge UX, or do I need to restructure our data categories such that we have a single root?

Here is the sample code from the docs; when I try this with our community it fails with an error "invalid data category or group".  If I use any one of our defined data categories it works fine, albeit for just that single category.

Comment: It's comes from profile level. Make sure ur profile has "All" data category added.

Comment: Yes; "All" was added.   I think we have it working now; the issue was the default visibility was set to "None".   Setting the visibility to "All Categories" seems to have done the trick

Comment: This is what I was asking to check. I will add as answer for more clarity to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visibility of data category is tightly coupled with Profile and Role. Usually, we develop solution and test using system admin account having all category access by default but when we test with non-admin profile we may fins issue because correct permission is not added on Profile or Role.

1. First, if your User's role has access to data category then you will be able to access it without drilling down 2nd and 3rd points.
2. If your user's profile has access to data category then you will be able to access it.
3. If User is assigned to any permission set and that permission set has access to data category then you will be able to access it.

More detail is given here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=category_visibility_whatis.htm&type=5